# How to send a directed reply from HippyBot

Tags: python, hipchat, hippybot

I am writing a custom plugin for [HippyBot](https://github.com/1stvamp/hippybot). I understand that the return value from a `@directcmd` annotated function will be prefaced with `@user` in the response.

I've also figured out that I can send additional messages to the channel using

```
@directcmd
def plugin(self, mess, args):
    self.bot.send_simple_reply(mess, "This is a plain message.")
    return "This will be a directed message."
```

Is there a way to send additional directed messages? Bonus points: Is there full API documentation anywhere?